# How to start and switch applications(APK) from a remote service?

Tags: android, android-service

I have two application and a remote service..
The remote service is subscribing to http server...
Now based on the web servers response i need to start or switch application.

Is it possible to directly trigger activity intents from remote service??
or should i have to create a broadcast receiver in both application and send signal from my remote service???

SOLUTION: 
Intent filter added to app manifest say

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ApplicationActivity134.android.intent.action" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

In your remote service add the intent trigger

```
Intent i = new Intent("ApplicationActivity134.android.intent.action");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try{
    this.startActivity(i); 
    }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Log.v(TAG, "ActivityNotFoundException @ Activity Invoking, Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It possible.

You must specify additional intent-filter for MAIN (activity which started when you click to app icon) activity.